# Azure Automation takes long to store xml into runbook sandbox

Tags: powershell, blobstorage, azure-automation

I have a PowerShell runbook which runs on Azure Automation. At a section the runbook retrieves a XML file from Azure Blob Storage. Average size of the file is about 6 kB.

During the first run it takes about a minute to retrieve the file from Azure Blob Storage and store it in the Azure Automation runbook sandbox at C:\temp.

At subsequent runs it takes up to 12 minutes to store the same file at the same location.

A code snippet scoped on the issue area:

```
$ConnectionName = "SubscriptionName"
$StorageAccountName = "StorageAccountName" 

Write-Output "Selecting subscription $ConnectionName"
$credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "CredentialName"
Add-AzureAccount -Credential $credential
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $ConnectionName
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $ConnectionName -CurrentStorageAccount $StorageAccountName 
Write-Output "Selected subscription $ConnectionName"

Write-Output "Retrieving XML from storage"
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob "FileName.xml" -Container "ContainerName" -Destination "C:\temp\" -Force
Write-Output "Retrieved XML from storage"
```

Does anyone has any idea about what I'm doing wrong?